# Upgraded Ubuntu to 11.04, No Menus

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, menu

I just upgraded to the new version of Ubuntu (11.04). 
Just like every time in the past, there are issues:

- My applications (firefox/gimp/anything) don't have menus (more critical).
- I have to manually run gnome-panel, how do I get it to run automatically? 
  Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the gnome panel thing, but the no-menus thing  it a "feature" of unity.

Type

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk
```

Then Log out and in. You should have menus in the window now.

Comment: done.. now what?

Comment: @Asaf, removing that you can expect menus to appear on the windows as was the case before 11.04.

Comment: Cleaning it up. You may want to log out and in again.

Comment: ok that rendered my entire GUI useless.. had to go to Console and write "sudo apt-get remove unity" and "sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart" for everything to go back to normal

Comment: Wow, it screwed every thing up? Thats the first thing I uninstall...

Answer (score 1):

Which profile are you logging in as? The profile that says Ubuntu, will take you to Unity and Ubuntu Classic Session will take you to the classic desktop.

All menus are now global, which means they are not attached to the windows, they appear on the top panel.
Btw, the global menus in Unity are hidden by default. You need to hover your mouse over the top panel to make them appear.

Answer (score 0):

For 12.04, you may have to de-install `indicator-appmenu`.  Unfortunately, this then keeps "Ubuntu Desktop" for top-left of your screen rather than the menu itself.  I've not found an answer to "do it right" using the Ubuntu shared menu and XMonad.